# How to connect battery pack with AC/DC out to marine amplifier with screw type terminal block connection?

Tags: batteries, amplifier

I have some basic questions about powering amplifiers and connection types that I could use help with. I'm trying to power some Peavey 10 inch satellite speakers on a bike trailer using a [lithium battery pack](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ME3ZH7C). The Lithium battery pack has an AC DC connection type ( 2.1mm X 5.5mm I think) and this connected fine with my basic [Pyle 90 amplifier](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0071HZ5LE). The problem was that this little setup didn't give the speakers enough (they were quiet). I also got too long of speaker cables so I'm sure that diminished it too.

I'm trying to get a bigger amp, but I'm noticing that most amplifiers have the screw type terminal block connection. I'm not sure if these are compatible or not or what would it take to be able to connect my lithium battery pack into an amp that has the screw type connections.

Can anyone give me some tips here? Is it possible to connect these two?

How to connect this?

[image]

to this?
[image]
Kenwood amp link: http://www.kenwood.com/usa/car/marine/kac-m3001/

Comment: Um... That 30A fuse pretty much tells you no...

Comment: @Trevor_G can you elaborate? Would a car battery or other lead acid give more amps?

Comment: General rule of thumb... if the connectors at the receiving end are bigger and beefier than the ones on your power supply... you need a bigger beefier power supply. And yes, these are designed to be direct from a big lead-acid car battery or some intermediate power conditioning.

Comment: Peavey are rated for  8 Ohms Sensitivity (1W/1m):
90 dB , Power rating: 50 watts avg, 100W pk 109 dB SPL

Answer (score 3):

The battery pack has an answered question on Amazon stating that the max draw is 3A:

[image]

The Kenwood amplifier lists 20A current draw.  Therefore, if you connect them, you will either A) blow a fuse inside the battery pack, or B) start a fire.

There are many larger batteries that are easily capable of sourcing 20A.  As you mentioned in a comment, a car battery should be able to handle the load.  You should be able to find a Lithium Ion battery that can handle it as well (one example is [this one](https://www.lithiumion-batteries.com/products/12v-25ah-lithium-ion-battery/)).  The important thing is making sure that the **max continuous discharge current is at least 20A** (preferably higher so that you have some margin).

Once you've picked the battery, it's just a matter of wiring the positive and negative terminals to your amp.  The AWG recommendations from https://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm indicate that you want AT LEAST 16AWG wire.

I'd recommend using spade or ring terminals rather than bare wire in the screw terminals - it will make the connection more reliable and less likely to break.

Answer (score 1):

You would just need a cable with the coaxial power connector on one end, and bare wires to connect to the screw terminals on the other end.

However, as Trevor mentions, the 30 amp fuse on the amplifier implies that the USB power pack is unlikely to supply enough current for the amplifier. (It would be useful to have a link to that Kenwood amplifier).

I see that the Pyle amplifier claims to have two, 45 watt channels, but only draws 24 watts (12V x 2 Amp), so those must be momentary peak advertising watts.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. It's this amp: http://www.kenwood.com/usa/car/marine/kac-m3001/ (Kenwood KAC-M3001).

Comment: Well actually you would need beefy power cables and fudge it into the little connector at the battery end... but I'm pretty sure no designer in his right mind would add a 30A fuse to a 2A unit.

Comment: Yup 300W per channel... that's up there in amps.

Comment: @Trevor_G just to check I'm following. You're saying that fuse is likely too large for that amp?

Comment: @KylePennell no I'm saying your battery pack will not deliver the amount of current/power the amplifier needs. (amp = amplifier here.. not "amps" current.) You are likely to fry the battery pack.. or have it blow up on you.

Comment: I would consider 14.7V LiPo pack with 50Ah $$$ or a deep cycle marine battery $ and good vibration isolation for the batteries on the trailer.  Although my 9V battery radio worked loud in the garage with old 12" Philips speakers in  a triangular bass reflex cabinet with about 1W

Comment: For my camping, a ghetto blaster and car battery would last all week of limited use at full power.